# Resource Governor IOPs counters - what are they counting?

Tags: sql-server, resource-governor

When profiling a resource group that is known to be write-heavy, I am seeing a number of the "**IOps write**" counters remain at zero or increment unexpectedly. specifically, the following counters...

```
select 
    write_io_completed_total, 
    write_io_stall_total_ms,
    write_bytes_total
from sys.dm_resource_governor_resource_pools;
```

It's worth noting that there appears to be a 1:1 correlation between [`dm_resource_governor_resource_pools`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-resource-governor-resource-pools-transact-sql) and [`dm_os_performance_counters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql) as below for some of these.

```
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| dm_resource_governor_resource_pools | dm_os_performance_counters   |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| write_io_completed_total            | Avg Disk Write IO (ms) Base  |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
| write_io_stall_total_ms             | Avg Disk Write IO (ms)       |
+-------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

The erratic behavior is reproducible via the below script...

- Behavior tested on `2017 (RTM)` & `2016 (SP1 CU5)`
- Repro scripts assume you are running on a sandbox instance - or at least one where you can trash the settings without worry.

#### Setup

```
use [master]
go
create resource pool demo_pool;
create workload group demo_group using demo_pool;
create login rg_login_sa with password='Plz_Halp_Me_StackExchange';
alter server role sysadmin add member rg_login_sa;
go
create or alter function dbo.GetResourceGroup()
returns sysname
with schemabinding
as
begin;
    declare @rg sysname = 'default';
    if original_login() = 'rg_login_sa' set @rg = 'demo_group'
    return @rg;
end;
go
alter resource governor with (classifier_function = dbo.GetResourceGroup);
alter resource governor reconfigure;
alter resource governor reset statistics;
```

#### Execution

Opening a session with the login `rg_login_sa`, execute the below.

```
use Sandbox
go
create table demoRGtbl (
    id int not null identity primary key,
    words char(4000) default '',
    dt datetime2(0) not null default getutcdate()
);
go
with cte as ( 
    select i=1
    union all
    select i+1
    from cte
    where i<1000000
)
insert dbo.demoRGtbl(words)
select top(1000)
    convert(varchar(100), newid())
from cte
option (maxrecursion 0);

waitfor delay '00:00:00.2';
go 100
```

...monitoring the performance counters in a separate session will reveal incrementing values in the `internal` resource pool...

```
select name,
       write_bytes_total,
       write_io_completed_total,
       write_io_stall_total_ms,
       read_bytes_total
from   sys.dm_resource_governor_resource_pools;
```

...while the `demo_pool` values remain unchanged from zero. Interestingly, the `read_bytes_total` for the `demo_pool` will begin to increment.

Attempting from the same session to insert rows to the table from itself show the same behavior as above...

```
insert dbo.demoRGtbl(words)
select words 
from dbo.demoRGtbl drg
```

... up until about the 100K-1MM row range - at which point the IOps counters begin incrementing to the `demo_pool` instance.

## My Questions

1. How do I reliable track IOps by Resource Group?
2. Is this a bug or expected behavior? If expected, what are the parameters in which a operation will log to these counters?

In other words - **what on earth am I currently tracking** in my production environment by using these counters?

See also: [Technet blog post announcing IO resource governance](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2013/11/07/io-resource-governance-in-sql-server-2014/).

---

#### Repro Cleanup

```
alter resource governor with (classifier_function = null)
alter resource governor disable;
go
drop workload group demo_group;
drop resource pool demo_pool;
drop login rg_login_sa;
drop function if exists [master].dbo.GetResourceGroup;
drop table if exists Sandbox.dbo.demoRGtbl;
go
```

Comment: Perhaps you can check: **https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/finding-the-source-of-your-sql-server-io.html**